# Is the following grammar a CFG?

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar, pushdown-automata

Language $L$ is defined over symbols $a,b,\#$

$$L=\{x\#y\mid x,y∈\{a,b\}^*, x\ne y, \lvert x\rvert=\lvert y\rvert\}$$

Is the above language context free?

Though both conditions separately are context free, but are they context free together?

Thanks.

Edit:

I just found a solution to the question. The above language is NOT Context Free. The same can be proved using pumping lemma for CFLs. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: If as suggested  $a,b$ are symbols of the language, does e.g. $|a|$ denote the length of string $a$? If so that is $1$ and your condition is redundant.

Comment: Sorry, x,y ∈{a,b}* I'm changing in the question too. Thanks for pointing out 

Comment: cs or cstheory SE might be better places to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Minor nit: The given language definition is not a grammar.

The language IS context-free.  Here is one grammar (note: the single-quotes merely mark the terminal symbols, they are not part of the language):

S -> L S L | A

A -> 'a' B 'b' | 'b' B 'a'

B -> L B L | '##'

L -> 'a' | 'b'

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you. Corrected my mistake in the question (L is a language and not a grammar). Thanks for the answer  Only correction is one # instead of two.